# how could I swap dims in keras with batch size?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, attention-model

I'd like to use attention in the CNN. the attention is (N,1) while N is the batch size. and I would like to change it to (1,N) and then use softmax.
Pytorch could do it using 'transpose'. But when I use 'Permute' in keras, there is the error:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_2: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

my code is here:

```
class AttentionModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.L = 500
        self.D = 128
        self.K = 1

        inputs = Input(shape=(28,28,1))
        result1 = self.feature_extractor_part1(inputs)
        result2 = self.feature_extractor_part2(result1)  # (N,500)

        attention=self.attention(result2) #(N,1)
        attention=Permute(dims=(2,1))(attention) #(1,N) !!PROBLEM!!
        attention=Flatten()(attention)
        attention=Activation('softmax')(attention) #(1,N)

        M=Dot()(attention,result2) #(K,L)

        final_result=self.classifer(M)

        self.model=Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=final_result)

        self.model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

    def feature_extractor_part1(self, inputs):
        conv1 = Conv2D(20, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(inputs)
        pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
        conv2 = Conv2D(50, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(pool1)
        pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

        return pool2

    def feature_extractor_part2(self, inputs):
        flat = Flatten()(inputs)
        dense = Dense(self.L, activation='relu')(flat)

        return dense

    def attention(self, inputs):
        flat1 = Dense(self.D, activation='tanh')(inputs)
        flat2 = Dense(self.K)(flat1)

        return flat2

    def classifer(self,inputs):
        result=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(inputs)

        return result
```

Comment: just change that line to `attention=Permute(dims=(0,2,1))(attention)`

Answer (score 2):

Use keras backend layer `transpose` wrapped with `Lambda` layer.
Something like:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model

seq = Input(shape=(1,))
mypermute = lambda x: K.transpose(x)
b = Lambda(mypermute)(seq)
model = Model(inputs=seq, outputs=b)
print(model.summary())
```

output:

```
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
> ================================================================= 
> input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 1)                 0
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> lambda_1 (Lambda)            (1, None)                 0
> ================================================================= 
> Total params: 
> 0 Trainable params: 
> 0 Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Nice answer, it was helpful for me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem for your `attention=Permute(dims=(2,1))(attention)` line is that you just neglect the batch dim. So it will output something like `(batch_size*, N)`, which is apparently wrong.

If you change it to `attention=Permute(dims=(0,2,1))(attention)` it will work. The output shape will be `(batch_size, 1, N)` as you requested.

Comment: it couldn't work. I mean the N is just the batch_size. I'd like to swap from (batch_size,1) to (1,batch_size)

Comment: @KZY Sorry about my mistake. Your code on that line isn't wrong. But the problem is `Flatten()`, which only accept tensor that has size like `(batch_size, *,*....)`, which should be at least has 3 dimensions. In your case, the output of your Permute layer is already `(batch_size, 1)`, so it doesn't need further flatten